# Change feed not trigger with multiple insert document in Cosmos DB

Tags: signalr, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, signalr-hub, serverless

I replicated the architecture below.
I insert the gps positions (document db) in cosmos db and in the javascript client (maps google) the pin moves.
All the step works: insert document db, trigger azure function and signalr that link client and document db in azure cosmos db.

[image: architecture]

The code to upload a document db in Cosmos:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document doc = client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName), estimatedPathDocument).Result.Resource;
ret[0] = doc.Id;
```

Azure function:

```
public static async Task Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> input, IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages, ILogger log)
{
    if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
    {
        var val = input.Select((d) => new
        {
            genKey = d.GetPropertyValue<string>("genKey"),
            dataType = d.GetPropertyValue<string>("dataType")
        }); 
        await signalRMessages.AddAsync(new SignalRMessage
        {
            UserId = val.First().genKey,
            Target = "tripUpdated",
            Arguments = new[] { input }
        });
    }
}
```

When I insert only one position the function in azure records the event and fire by moving the pin.

The problem is when I insert sequentially a series of positions in an almost instantaneous way and this does not trigger the function for the document following the first one.

Only if i insert a delay only some documents fire the trigger:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document doc = client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName), estimatedPathDocument).Result.Resource;
Thread.Sleep(3000);
ret[0] = doc.Id;
```

I don't know if I load the documents correctly, but even managing them in an asynchronous way (see under), it almost seems like the trigger is triggered only when the document in cosmos db is "really / physically" created.

```
Task.Run(async () => await AzureCosmosDB_class.MyDocumentAzureCosmosDB.CreateRealCoordDocumentIfNotExists_v1("axylog-cdb-01", "axylog-collection-01", realCoord, uri, key));
```

The solution can be to list the documents in a queue and load them on azure cosmos sequentially after a delay of about ten seconds one from the other?

Comment: Are those, documents with different ids?

Comment: @NickChapsas yes ...

Comment: Tom, the Trigger will not retry if there is any exception within the user code. Could you wrap your Function code in a try/catch block to identify any possible failures? Also, the Trigger will send batches of documents, so your documents could be all included in a single Trigger execution. In your Azure Functions logs you can see the Trigger and the # of docs included in the batch. Do you see logs regarding the scenario when you are inserting multiple documents?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I wrapped the function but there are not errors ...
The output is active:

`25T14:17:34.1386796Z', Id=eb88087d-8743-4df5-9cca-f49ec2ced3a5)
2019-01-25T14:17:34.140 [Information] genKey: "428_2019_6-3426320"
2019-01-25T14:17:34.140 [Information] dataType: "tripHead"
2019-01-25T14:17:34.145 [Information] Executed 'Functions.updateTrip' (Succeeded, Id=eb88087d-8743-4df5-9cca-f49ec2ced3a5) (...)`

But sometimes some document is not triggered (despite the 3 second delay between the insertions of the documents)... and the pin don't move obviously.

Comment: That is odd. Do you have any other Function monitoring the same collection (it could be running locally in your computer)? This can be identified if you browse your Leases collection and you find documents with different values in the Owner attribute.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta It works. "..your documents could be all included in a single Trigger execution" in fact i have in input: IReadOnlyList<Document> input.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, do you mean that it's working correctly now?

Comment: Yes... i modify the trigger like this:

`log.LogInformation("Documents count " + input.Count.ToString());
            foreach (var el in input)
            {
                await signalRMessages.AddAsync(new SignalRMessage
                {
                    UserId = el.GetPropertyValue<string>("genKey"),
                    Target = "tripUpdated",
                    Arguments = new[] { el }
                });
            }`